# Count filtered statuses from Twitter

Tags: java, twitter4j

What is the easiest way to count the number of filtered statuses that come in from a twitter stream?  I know I can filter statuses using the FilterQuery like so:

```
FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
    String[] array = { "twitter" };
    fq.track(array);

    twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

But how would I be able count the number of statuses that come in containing the word twitter?  I have tried numerous different ways which have all but failed and only led to all statuses showing up.  I even tried to parse json to filter the "text" part in order to count but it became too confusing and did not work.

Comment: Aren't you searching for this? https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#count

Comment: Sorry my question was badly phrased. I am not talking about the count parameter but instead I am talking about literally counting each tweet that comes in. For example I want to run the streamer and have it tell me that 7 tweets or whatever with my filtered word in them have come in since the time I ran the streamer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already filtering for statuses that contain 'twitter' all you need to do is increment a `count` in the [`StatusListener#onStatus(Status)`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/StatusListener.html#onStatus-twitter4j.Status-) method, e.g.:

```
final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();

StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatus(Status status) {
        count.getAndIncrement();
    }

    // omitted...
}

twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.filter(fq);

// wait (to allow statuses to be received) then halt the steam...

System.out.println("received " + count.get() + "statuses in total");
```

Alternatively you could create a `CountingStatusListener` that provided you with the count when you were done processing the stream.

Regarding your comment:

> For example I want to run the streamer and have it tell me that 7 tweets or whatever with my filtered word in them have come in since the time I ran the streamer.

You probably already know this but the streaming-api provides a real-time view of statuses flowing through Twitter (albeit a sample) so when you stop processing a stream you will miss any statuses sent between the time you stop until you start processing again.

I hope that helps.